# Starting Web APIs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am asked to create a web api for a desktop application that is already developed.

I don t have any background in web development in general and I am somehow stuck in doing it in a very short amount of time

I found several books and guides out there but non of them is to the point and require alot of time ... which I don t have at all .

Can someone guide me to a good how to start tutorial page ? I have basic C# .NET experience and using Visual studio 2012

Comment: Web api. What do you mean, like web pages, or a web service?

Comment: it is the new version of web services , stackoverflow defines it as follow: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-api/info

Comment: @Ek0nomik Thank you for the link you provided . this is where I started but with all due respect I didn t really like this one because when I switched to Firefox I didn t get the outcome result as they are showing . Which made me get confused and started looking somewhere else ... do you have other resources ? again thank you very much . it is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[Your First ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Comment: Thank you for the link you provided .(this is the same link that Ek0nomik provided but the answe was deldted) this is where I started but with all due respect I didn t really like this one because when I switched to Firefox I didn t get the outcome result as they are showing . Which made me get confused and started looking somewhere else ... do you have other resources ? again thank you very much . it is much appreciated

Comment: As per my understanding you are having problem with actually finding  the output of what you did with ASP.net Webapi. I will recommend you that you use POSTMAN which is a chrome extension. This extension is very self explanatory and will allow you to GET and POST in format you like JSON , XML , TEXT etc...

Comment: ASP.NET have a big community, so there is many tutorials online.
Browes [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/get-started) or there is some more on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp).

Comment: @TabishSarwar when I tried to use Firefox , It gave me the same page as in Internet Explorer and not the XML fomrat

Comment: @MichalKowalkowski I know that there are many tutorials out there . I just needed something straight to the point. many of them are very long to follow

Comment: Can you do WireShark to see thing passing back and forth? Or Can you try POSTMAN on chrome as i suggested. Type in the URL .Do a GET Request and see what you get. If nothing happens there. We will see from there. There could be something that you missed .